# Can we support number localization using moment.js

Tags: localization, momentjs

```
var x = 3500;
var y = x.momentJSApi("hindi");
console.log(y);//y = ३,५००
```

Expected  :- ३,५००(based on locale the y value should change)
Want to support number localization.

Comment: 3500, this is your input and expected output :- ३,५०० ?

Comment: @Durga yes that is the expected

Comment: Then what is the use of momentjs, as you are not working with date anyway.